# JSON not getting included when running from Beanshell Jmeter

Tags: javascript, json, curl, jmeter, beanshell

We have a `CURL` command which basically pushes the status of the run to a dashboard. Below is the command with a dummy URL.

The command has to send two information details to the dashboard; `info` and `info` which has contents `Text is missing` and `Please check.` This curl command when executed from any `Linux` box is running correctly and the information sent in the `JSON` is being displayed but when we try to run the same command from `Jmeter Beanshell`, it is running successfully but the info in the JSON alone is not coming to the dashboard.

```
String command = "curl -X POST -d \"status=GREEN\" -d 'info={\"error\":[{\"info\":\"Text is missing\"},{\"info\":\"Please check.\"}]}' abc.com/api/run-dashboard/apikey=456655656";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
#to display the output-
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder everything = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while( (line = in.readLine()) != null) 
    {
      everything.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    log.info("OUTPUT: " + everything.toString());
    }
```

We tried adding the additional header `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` in the beanshell but in vain.

Can someone let us know what is missing in our command which is sent from Beanshell on why JSON data is not being displayed. shold we add any other header details.

Answer (score 0):

1. You might need to provide full path to `curl` utility like `/usr/bin/curl`
2. It might be the case your command fails with some error so make sure to handle [p.getErrorStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream--)
3. Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), consider switching to it as Beanshell performance might be a big question mark. Moreover you will be able to convert your Beanshell code into something like:

   ```
   def response = "curl -X POST -d \"status=GREEN\" -d 'info={\"error\":[{\"info\":\"Text is missing\"},{\"info\":\"Please check.\"}]}' http://example.com/api/run-dashboard/apikey=456655656".execute().text
   log.info(response)
   ```

   [image: JMeter Groovy Curl]

   More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've added the same in the JSR223 sampler and it executed successfully but the JSON data is not getting displayed in the dashboard. the exact same command when executed from linux machines runs and dashboard even displays the JSON information.

Comment: I think rather than using the full path for curl which is linux, we need to provide the curl path of windows.